# django to change the value of varible in template based on the number

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

there is a model books

where i want to fetch  all the objects  and display it to user using django templates

```
books=books.objects.all()
```

and with django template tag im able to fetch the values in the model and display them

but is there any way where django can change the variable values based on the number

for example this part :

```
 {% for b in books %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{b.books_id}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

this will display all the id's
but is there any way to override this in django

Lets say

for instance ,if the `b.books_id` for any  object is  1
then it should display  something like "completed"

if its 2 then it should display something  like "no"

is there any possibility to do that ??
using `if` or f`or loops` in django template tags
or through views

Answer (score 0):

Yes tout have if statement in Django templates (replace b.books_id by name of the objects which contains 1 or 2):

```
{% for b in books %}
    {% if b.books_id == "1" %}
        Completed
    {% elif b.books_id == "2" %}
        No
    {% else %}
        ???
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```